# Consuming a SOAP web service secured with oauth

Tags: java, soap, oauth, oauth-1.0a

Does anyone know how I can add a consumer key and consumer secret to consume a SOAP web service secured by OAuth1.0a ? I am trying to add this key and secret to soap header before I make a call to soap service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue and posted a blog post about it here https://betterjavacode.com/2017/05/08/how-to-consume-oauth-secured-soap-web-service/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers.